# how to zero every bit when in second operand is 1?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

example:

```
1010111110110001
0101011100010010
================
1010100010100001

 |0 1
-|----
0|0 1
1|0 0
```

how to do this operation in c++ /c++11 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do a bitwise NOT and then AND them: `a & ~b`

Given:

```
 a     = 1010111110110001
 b     = 0101011100010010
```

Then negating `b` gives:

```
~b     = 1010100011101101
```

and doing `a & ~b`:

```
 a     = 1010111110110001
~b     = 1010100011101101
-------------------------
a & ~b = 1010100010100001
```

Answer (score 6):

simple:

```
result = op1 & ~op2;
```

this inverts the second operand bitwise (1 becomes 0 and vice versa). After this you use a bitwise and. This is often called using a bitmask.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do a bitwise AND with the bitwise negation:

```
result = val1 & ~val2;
```

Answer (score 4):

You want a bitwise AND of the compliment of the second operand.

```
int fun(int x, int y)
{
    return x & ~y;
}
```